# Presheaf on a topological space

Tags: category-theory

Consider the category of all open sets of a given topological space where the morphism are inclusions,why one can see a Presheaf as a contravariant functor?

Comment: By definition of "contravariant functor".

Comment: I'd say by definition of presheaf. (The definition I know is "contravariant functor from the poset-category of open sets"...)

Comment: @Zhen Lin: but obviously that cannot be Jr.'s definition.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose your presheaf $F$ has values in some category, say rings. Then to each open $U $ there corresponds a ring $F(U)$, and to the inclusion map $U\to V$ where $U\subseteq V$ there corresponds map $V\to U$ in the opposite direction, sometimes called the restriction.

Then you should verify that the axioms of a functor hold. The domain of your functor is just the poset category where the objects are open sets and the morphisms are inclusion maps

Answer (score 0):

Because presheaf deals with restriction. Please read 1st chapter of Red book by Mumford for more details. It is explained very well there.